# Is there a model.config file for tensorflow-serving to return all the models at the host

Tags: docker, tensorflow-serving

I have followed the instruction of tensorflow serving and using docker could run 3 models by specifying their versions. But as the output at the host i get only the latest version of the model. Is there any model.config file that cna help display all three models at the host?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out!!
This is how you can do it

1. Include model_config file in the folder where the models are present

   ```
    model_config_list: {
      config: {
        name: "half_plus_three",
        base_path: "/models/half_plus_three"
        model_platform: "tensorflow",
        model_version_policy: {all: {}}
    }
   ```

   }
2. Run the command

   ```
   docker run -t --rm -p 8501:8501 \
     -v "$(pwd)/models/:/models/" tensorflow/serving \
     --model_config_file=/models/models.config \
     --model_config_file_poll_wait_seconds=60
   ```